# AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests http request

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mocking, httpwebrequest

i try to write a test with

```
AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
```

somewhere deep in my beans

```
FacesContext currentInstance = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
```

is called, but there is no request so it returns null.
Is there a way to fake a complete http request in my tests?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's a way, there is always a way. Spring provides a whole hierarchy of servlet mock objects in the spring-test artifact. You can use a [`MockHttpRequest`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html). But how you can tie that to `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` is beyond my understanding of JSF. You'll probably need a Mock JSF implementation somewhere along the way.